# NCP1654 current Mirror

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

Regarding the [NCP1654](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1654-d.pdf), there is a circuit in the IC block diagram that I don't fully understand. Could you please take a look at the figure below and help me understand the blue and red lines?

[image]

below are my questions,

1. Is the blue line also referred to as the current mirror?
2. If both circuits are current mirrors, does the red line circuit resemble the blue line circuit?
3. If the red line circuit is different from the blue line circuit, could you please describe how the red line circuit is structured?

Comment: I have doubts that circuit is accurate. It would make more sense to me if there was another diode-connected transistor from the base of the left transistor to ground. I could be missing something, of course.

Comment: You have more details in the data-sheet of the [NCP1653](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1653-d.pdf) which was introduced before the 1654. The principle is to keep the CS pin at 0 V so that you can read the current as \$I_S=I_L\frac{R_{CS}}{R_S}\$. What you show is a simplistic view of what is inside the circuit.

Comment: @VerbalKint
is The current mirror used to draw the current to make sure the CS pin is 0V?

Comment: @VerbalKint 
This pin sources a current IS which is proportional to the inductor current IL.
So, does it use the current mirror to draw the same current in the IC to do the overcurrent protection?

Comment: I have rolled back additions you have made to your post that are unrelated to the questions you originally asked, nor to the questions I have answered.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, 

After thinking, I understand what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is [the circuit within] the blue line also referred to as the current mirror?

Assuming the circuit within the OP's blue lines is accurate, here is how it works.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff5y25.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage on the bases of the transistors may vary a little depending upon operating conditions, but the difference between Vdd and the voltage on the bases will relatively constant, say

$$Vbb = Vdd - 0.65V$$

So, the current through R1 will be approximately

$$I_{R1} = \frac{Vdd - 0.65}{R1}$$

If we assume there is no current out of the emitter of Q1, that is the CS pin is drawing no current, then all of the current through R1 will pass through the base of Q2. So, Iout will be approximately

$$I_{out0} = \beta I_{R1}$$

We will assume that the transistors are matched, and that \$\beta = \beta_{Q1} = \beta_{Q2}\$.

Now, if current is drawn out through the CS pin of the IC, (Iin in our diagram) current will be drawn through the base and collectors of Q1.
Ib(Q1) will be approximately

$$I_{b(Q1)} \approx \frac{I_{in}}{\beta}$$

This current is *stolen* from the base of Q2, so

$$I_{out} \approx I_{out0} - I_{in}$$

I wouldn't exactly call this a current mirror. Rather the input current is *subtracted* from a "quiescent" current to form the output.

> If the red line circuit is different from the blue line circuit, could you please describe how the red line circuit is structured?

It probably looks something quite like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feDRL6.png)</sup>

There may be additional resistors and transistors to improve accuracy, but that is the basic current mirror circuit. For a current mirror,

$$I_{out} \approx I_{in}$$

Note the absence of the "quiescent" current \$I_{out0}\$ found in the first circuit.

Edit:

Because the bases of Q1 and Q2 are tied together, if both transistors are conducting, their emitters will be at similar potentials within a few 10s of mV. That is, the emitter of Q1, when it is conducting, will be within a few 10s of mV from ground. From the point of view of the voltage across \$R_{cs}\$ (from the schematic in the datasheet), these few 10s of mV may not be that significant. However, when the two emitters are *exactly* at the same potential, given the assumption of matched transistors, then current  \$I_{R1}\$ will be equally divided between the bases of Q1 and Q2. This will make the output current \$\frac{I_{out0}}{2}\$.

Comment: According to Verbal Kint's description.
The principle is to keep the CS pin at 0 V.
So, I am a little confused about how to use a current mirror to make sure the CS pin is 0V.

Comment: I also put the NCP1653 datasheet on it.
In NCP1653, it only uses the current mirror there. 
I still don't very understand, what's the function of the current mirror.

Comment: @PowerJJ Because the bases of Q1 and Q2 are tied together, if both are conducting, (and they are matched) their emitters will be at similar  potentials within some few 10s of mVs.

Comment: Sorry, 
Could you explain in more detail why the CS pin voltage will be 0V?
I mean how does current mirrow connect to CS pin?

Comment: The current mirror in your circuit does not connect to the CS pin, although it does in the NCP1653. Vbe for a conducting transistor stays within a fairly small range. Since base potentials are equal, emitter potentials will be in a small range. The overall feedback of the system may make that range even smaller.

Comment: OK, I think I should read the datasheet more detai.

Comment: Do you think the figure is wrong?

Comment: The figure shows a block diagram with schematic elements mixed in. The schematic elements may be more suggestive of the actual circuit than an exact representation.  In the absence of more detailed documentation, I cannot tell you for sure.

Comment: "OK, I think I should read the datasheet more detai" Do you understand my point that if the bases are tied together, the emitters will be at similar potentials?

Comment: Sorry, 
I don't very understand " if the bases are tied together, the emitters will be at similar potentials"
I try to use simulation to observe the waveform, but the CP pin is not at 0V.
I post my simulation  result in the context

Comment: The emitter voltage is 3.6V?
the inductor current is not constant, it looks like a triangular waveform, how to make sure the CS pin is always 0V? I am very confsued

Comment: Why did you add Rs2? It doesn't belong there. You need to understand "if the bases are tied together, the emitters will be at similar potentials". Otherwise you are just in over your head.

Comment: Yes, I understood.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The NCP1654 hosts a circuit which keeps the pin at 0 V during operation. The injected current \$I_{CS}\$ develops a positive voltage across resistor \$R_{OCP}\$ which compensates the negative voltage dropped across the sense resistor:

[image]

Therefore, the internally-generated current is equal to \$I_{CS}=\frac{R_{sense}}{R_{OCP}}I_L\$. The picture is coming from the [NCP1655](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1655-d.pdf) data-sheet.

The internal circuit shown in the 1654 is over-simplified but still is representative of what the controller does. If the right-side transistor base is at 0.6 V and, provided the transistors are rigorously paired, then the emitter of the left-side transistor is at 0 V.